# What is the return URL of ubercart after successful payment

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I have the following code in my simple ubercart payment gateway module to redirect it to my merchant payment form after checkout:

```
  $data = array(
  'merchantId' => "1",  
  'amount' => $total,
  'orderRef' => $order->order_id,
  'currCode' => 608,
  'successUrl' => 'http://mydomain.com/cart/checkout/complete',
  'failUrl' => 'http://mydomain.com/Fail.html',
  'cancelUrl' => 'http://mydomain.com/Cancel.html',
  'payType' => 'N',
  'lang' => 'E',
  'pdesc' => t('You have !num_of_products products in your cart', array('!num_of_products' => count($order->products))),
);

$form['#action'] = 'https://test.mymerchantgateway.com/payment/pay.jsp';
```

In the code above I can initiate payment successfully. The problem is on how to return to my site and mark the order as complete. After some research, I added "http://mydomain.com/cart/checkout/complete" as the return url to my site but it's not working.

Any know what is the correct return url in order to mark the ubercart order after checkout as complete?

I am using drupal 6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your custom payment module, you have to create your own redirect url
(you can create one for all cases [success, error, cancel] and redirect upon status message returned):

#### 1.Specify a menu callback and a function to catch the POST variables returned by your payment gateway

e.g   for module name: uc_mypayment

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_menu().
 */
function uc_mypayment_menu() {
  $items['cart/mypayment/complete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Order complete',
    'page callback' => 'uc_mypayment_complete',
    'access callback' => 'uc_mypayment_completion_access',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'uc_mypayment.pages.inc',
  );
}
```

#### 2.Then you have to implement the callback function which is the one that handles the returned variables:

```
function uc_mypayment_complete($cart_id = 0) {
  $order_id = check_plain($_POST['Param1']);
  $payment_status = check_plain($_POST['Result']);
  $payment_amount = check_plain($_POST['Charge']);
  $payment_currency = check_plain($_POST['Currency']);
  $ErrorMessage = check_plain($_POST['ErrorMessage']);
  ...
}
```

tweak it according to your gateway protocol.

#### 3.Depending on the status and message you get back, you may redirect to the corresponding status page (i.e success, error, cancel) e.g

```
//assuming you have saved your success, error and cancel Urls into the variables: uc_mypayment_success_return_url, uc_mypayment_error_return_url, uc_mypayment_cancel_return_url

switch ($payment_status) {
    case 1: // successful transaction
        $comment = t('MyPaymentGateway transaction ID: @PayId', array('@PayId' => $PayId));
        uc_payment_enter($order->order_id, 'myPaymentGateway', $payment_amount, $order->uid, NULL, $comment);
        uc_cart_complete_sale($order);
        uc_order_comment_save($order->order_id, 0, t('Payment of @amount @currency submitted through myPaymentGateway.', array('@amount' =>   $price , '@currency' => $payment_currency)), 'order', 'payment_received');
        uc_order_comment_save($order->order_id, 0, t('MyPaymentGateway reported a payment of @amount @currency', array('@amount' =>   $payment_amount , '@currency' => $payment_currency)));
        drupal_set_message($debugmessage . t('Your payment was completed.'));
        drupal_goto(variable_get('uc_mypayment_success_return_url', 'cart'));
        break;  
    case 2: //error
        $message = $debugmessage . t("Your payment failed with following error message: @Error", array('@Error' => $ErrorMessage));
        uc_order_comment_save($order->order_id, 0, $message, 'admin');
        drupal_set_message($message . t(' Please try again in a few moments.'));
        drupal_goto(variable_get('uc_mypayment_error_return_url', 'cart'));
    break;
    case 3: //user cancelled
        uc_order_comment_save($order->order_id, 0, t("The customer cancelled payment."), 'order', 'canceled' );
        drupal_set_message($debugmessage .t('Your payment was cancelled. Please feel free to continue shopping or contact us for assistance.'));
        unset($_SESSION['cart_order']);
        drupal_goto(variable_get('uc_mypayment_cancel_return_url', 'cart'));
    break;
}
```

Now you can just supply one url for all cases, in this example: cart/mypayment/complete

Comment: I need your advice. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185961/return-url-of-ubercart-after-successful-payment